# XML error: "Too many descriptors open"

Tags: java

I am parsing a huge XML file in Java and found the following error message: *Too many descriptors open*. Initially, i was thinking that we should split the XML file into multiple files and then parse it. Is it the way to go for? I don't want to change any specification related to memory.

Comment: How are you parsing it? If you split up the file, you'll have no longer valid XML, so this can't be an option.

Comment: Also, a piece of code with the line(s) causing this error would be nice (or at least show us how you open the files, since it seems to be the problem here).

Comment: Hi Ray: This was my initial thinking whether it is feasible or not that's what i want to know. So i think it is not possible as per your knowledge. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: NaeiKinDus: Hi I cannot put the code here but i can tell you how it works.We are reading the file and in startelement() and endelement() we are checking for the tags one by one. Is there any way to reduce the no of file descriptors opened so that the issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you where using `DOM parser`. `DOM` is not suitable for the Large XML file parsing. Since, `DOM Parser` creates an In Memory tree representation of XML file and then parses it. So use `SAX parser`. Since, This is an event based XML Parsing and it parse XML file step by step, so much suitable for large XML Files.

Comment: Ashok: No we are using SAX parser . Reading the file tags one by one and get the content of the tags , finally checking the end tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved if you will close the open FDs in the code.